# how to remove product from cart in woo-commerce without page refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

how to remove product from cart in woo-commerce without page refresh. now this time the product is deleted properly but page is reload every time . i want to delete product without reload the page

```
<?php
    echo apply_filters( 
        'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', 
        sprintf( 
            '<a href="%s" class="remove" title="%s">&times;</a>', 
            esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ), 
            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ) 
        ), 
        $cart_item_key 
    );
?>
```